# Spring support /{user-id} & /me by same method in URL

Tags: java, spring, url, spring-mvc, spring-security

Is there a native spring way to support /me url patterns in @Controller, like it's done in facebook API.

Basically what I want is to be able to do is, by specify @Controller like this:

```
@Controller
public class PlayerProfileController {

     @Override
     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = PROFILE_PLAYER, produces = PRODUCES)
     public @ResponseBody PlayerProfile getPlayerProfile(@PathVariable("player") String playerId) {   
          ...
     }
}
```

Support urls like:

- /profile/234
- /profile/123
- /profile/me - which would be translated to current user id, before it reaches controller

This seems to be pretty common our days.

Comment: can you write the value of the constant `PROFILE_PLAYER`?

Comment: How about using a different method for '/me' and then forward to the /{user_id} from that method?

Comment: This is one option, but I would rather do it generically, throgh a filter, then have it in each controller I'm creating, and I don't need more granular access for now.